# Adding formatting to sent email from powershell script

Tags: email, powershell, formatting

I'm looking to send an email using powershell that would look something like below

The Data audit has at least one problem. The following is the audit

- There are 15 rows that are too large
- There are 37 rows that are too small
- There are no null asOfDates
- There are 55 rows with stale asOfDates

This audit will run again in 15 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `send-mailmessage` with html parameter and format the body of the message with html tags.

Comment: perfect! i'm slightly confused as to how I would put a variable in there. can it be as simple as -body <h1>$asOfDate</h1>?

Comment: Read here http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/6320/Default.aspx